# passing date parameters from oracle sql to crystal report

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports, report

I'm trying to pass a date parameters from sql to crystal report.

I created a parameter at command named tdate then I wrote the following in the sql

```sql
H.DATEG >=TO_DATE ({?tdate}, 'DD/MM/YYYY' )
H.DATEG >=TO_DATE ('{?tdate}', 'DD/MM/YYYY' )
```

and they both give me errors
can you helo me please?

Comment: Can you provide the error message?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `{?tdate}` is a `date`, the proper Command syntax is:

```
...
WHERE TRUNC(H.DATEG) = {?tdate}
```